# Conversion of DOCX to PDF using PHPDOCX

Tags: laravel, lumen, phpdocx

I am very new to laravel lumen and Phpdocx. I have a .docx file which I am trying to convert into .pdf as follows -

```
$docx = new \Phpdocx\Create\CreateDocx();
$docx->transformDocument('document.docx', 'document.pdf');
```

But this is not converting the document not even throwing any error. Can anyone please help me in achieving my aim. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want us to say. Without an error this is tricky. However, can you confirm that `document.docx` exists? Maybe specify an absolute path to see if that works.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: I have added absolute file path but still its not working and throwing error as - rename(C:\Users\user\Desktop/document.pdf,C:\Users\user\Desktop\document.pdf): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Comment: I am getting above error in - vendor\phpdocx\Classes\Phpdocx\Transform\TransformDocAdvLibreOffice.php (line 185)

and line 185 is - 

rename($newDocumentPath, $target);

Answer (score 1):

From the docs : https://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/conversion-plugin/conversion-plugin-installation-and-set-up

Make sure you are setting the right configurations.
File : config\phpdocxconfig.in

```
; libreoffice, native, msword, openoffice
method = "libreoffice"

; libreoffice installation path, absolute path
path = "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice"
;path = '"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe"'


; custom HOME folder; allows setting a custom HOME folder when doing the transformations using LibreOffice
;home_folder = ""
```